# Create Array From String w/ Commas in Values

Tags: php

If I have a example string like this: `"dataset1"=>"blank","gdataset"=>"f1,f2"`

I'm trying to create an array of the key/value pairs.
Desired array result should look like this:

```
Array(
 [0] => "dataset1"=>"blank"
 [1] => "gdataset"=>"f1,f2"
)
```

I've tried http_build_query & explode w/o success, as the array key or value is getting mangled.

What should I use to get the desired array?

Comment: Just curious, why wouldn't you want: `Array(
 "dataset1"=>"blank",
 "gdataset"=>"f1,f2"
)`

Comment: Oh, I had to think about what you were asking, but I need to keep the key/value pairs together as a string, as I will potentially write them back into a file, exactly as you see them here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of hackish, but just replace `","` with `"",""` to keep the quotes and then explode on `","`:

```
$result = explode('","', str_replace('","', '"",""', $string));
```

But I'm positive that there is a much better way to do whatever you are doing in general.  Maybe a new question outlining why you are doing this?

Comment: Thanks,  I knew there must of been a relatively easy way to do this ;)